# Az Login command not working on Kudu power shell

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line-interface, kudu

I have an ASP.Net web application deployed on Azure App service. This application tries to login to Azure using the power shell command 'az login'. But, I am getting an error saying that 'the term az is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet'. After this, I went to the App service on the portal > Advanced Tools > Debug Console > PowerShell > Then I executed the same az login command, but still got the same error. Please suggest what needs to be done in this case.

Answer (score 0):

this means that `az` is not installed on the web app hosts. nothing you can really do, unless you install it first.